# What is the model of fast CAD printer used in Pentagon Wars?

Tags: printer, identify-this-peripheral

Panning shots of a seemingly fast (CAD?) printer are shown in *Pentagon Wars*, for example in this clip at timecode 8:34: https://youtu.be/aXQ2lO3ieBA?t=514

[image]

What is it, and how does it work?

Comment: The film in question is labeled comedy, so the "plotter" might be something the filmmakers dreamed up and simply outputs a preprinted paper.

Comment: Even in a "serious" film meant to be very historically accurate, you'd pretty much always use a pre-printed prop page rather than trying to do a print live on camera.  Losing production time debugging and replacing ink would be a major problem.  A real printer is always much louder than a simple slot you shove some paper through, etc.

Answer (score 11):

If this is a plotter, it might be an electrostatic plotter. But it looks far more likely to be a blueprint copier (or heliographic copier) which isn't a computer device at all.

Comment: TIL about "electrostatic plotters" (thanks!) - I thought plotters were all [sharpie-robots](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tr7Mbw9gLpk).

Comment: In my recollection, the last time I looked at a modern “plotter” it was a giant inkjet printer. I do miss the dance of a honest-to-goodness plotter; I could stare at them for hours…

Comment: My house is filled with "sharpie robots", some of which can be used as (very slow) optical digitizers. Electrostatics were the very large format, professional plotters that big engineering shops used. They were very expensive. The mechatronics boom of the 1980s and early 1990s made pen plotters fast enough and large enough to out-compete the big electro plotters

Comment: @scruss Can you elaborate on that "optical digitizer" remark?

Comment: This definitely looks like a Heliographic (or Diazo) copier.

Comment: They had a plotter where I worked in 1969.  That was before Sharpies.

Comment: [Paul Rickards](https://twitter.com/PaulRickards) produces interesting artwork with vintage plotters; I find it fascinating to see how much time and how many pens it takes to produce some of his more complex pieces!

Comment: HP has a site on their old pen plotters: http://www.hpmuseum.net/exhibit.php?class=4&cat=24

Comment: They are not “sharpies”. They are high precision refillable ink pens used in technical drafting which most people just call by the trademark Rapidograph. Perfectly uniform and smooth lines every time, typically available at several widths between 0.1mm and 0.4mm. A true joy to draft with, although not appropriate for handwriting because you really need to keep the pen perpendicular to the paper. They are a beautiful but delicate writing instrument: I’ve seen many a pen destroyed after rolling down from the drafting table uncapped.

Comment: @Dai - sure: [Pen plotters: not just output devices … – We Saw a Chicken …](https://scruss.com/blog/2016/05/17/pen-plotters-not-just-output-devices/). The drafting sight is an optical sight that replaces the pen, and you can move it with the plotter's cursor control  and query the position from HP-GL

Comment: @Jon that’s not HP, it’s the HP Computer Museum, which isn’t affiliated with HP ;-). See the bottom of any page on the site.

Comment: @StephenKitt - fair enough - still brings back some nostalgic memories, including changing pens on the fly when I wanted more than the 4 available on the carousel.

Comment: @EuroMicelli I used Rotring pens in school but I don't know if they were _Rapidograph_ or not - but the Rotring pens I did use had a weird flat cylendrical nib that I've no idea how it worked - unfortunately Rotring's website doesn't tell me how their nibs work either. Anyway, I assumed that the HP plotters _had_ to use felt-tipped pens (i.e. Sharpies) because a ball-point wouldn't work for dots and short strokes - and need lots of cleaning.

Comment: @Jon yes, it’s a great resource, and a nice walk down memory lane...

Comment: @Dai, you are completely correct. A ballpoint pen would never work. A Rapidograph has no problems with short strokes, points, or even a dotted line (*peck, peck, peck, peck, peck…*). I used Rotring as well and they sell/sold under the trademark Variograph; We still called them Rapidographs and they work the same way.

Comment: @EuroMicelli so.. _how_ do Rapidograph nibs work then? :)

Comment: *shrug* :-) I have ideas but I don’t know for sure. Sorry. And it’s way out of scope for Retrocomputing SE, and it wouldn’t belong in comments anyway even if it were. I would bet there is a patent somewhere with all the details on it

Comment: @EuroMicelli - pressurized ballpoint pens for plotters worked quite well. The good ones were made by the Fisher (Space Pen) Company, and are still available. Fibre-tip pens were standard (though water based, unlike Sharpies) with ceramic tip and  metal-tipped technical/drafting pens for more specialized work.

Comment: @PeterI - the analogue dials on the device made me think it couldn't be a plotter, so was most likely a copier ​zhooshed up to look like something fancy

Comment: Kind of fast to be a plotter of any kind.